# Changing the format of a date in a string

Tags: date, stata

I have the following string name/date/country variable:

```
"John Peters|2016-01-19|England"
```

How can I get the variable to read as:

```
"John Peters|january|England"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
clear
input str30 loandate
"John Peters|2016-01-19|England" 
end

split loandate, parse("|")

generate loandate2b = month(date(loandate2, "YMD"))

egen loandate_new = concat(loandate1 loandate2b loandate3), format(%tdMonth) punct("|")

list loandate_new

     +-----------------------------+
     |                loandate_new |
     |-----------------------------|
  1. | John Peters|January|England |
     +-----------------------------+
```